# react-native-maps in react-native-swiper - How to disable

Tags: react-native

I have a MapView in a Swiper-component. I have disabled the "moving" of the MapView by setting `scrollEnabled` to `false` but the `Swiper` is still not reacting on left and right swipes.

The zooming should be still possible so a transparent overlay would be not an option.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: A hacky idea: cover the map with a transparent view

Comment: "The zooming should be still possible so a transparent overlay would be not an option."

Comment: Ah sorry. Does it happen on both platforms or just android?

Comment: Can you give any snippet?

Comment: I've tried the same thing. react-native-maps inside react-native-swiper with zoom enabled and scroll disabled. It's working fine for me.